# switching to rake db:schema:load with Rubber.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubber

I've searched all over the internet and through the deploy files that come with Rubber, but can't figure out how to do this.

When I try to deploy to EC2, the script fails when it tries to run `rake db:migrate`. I know it would not fail if it tried to run `rake db:schema:load`, but I can't figure out how to change the script to run `rake db:schema:load` instead.

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an answer, but I just switched to using Heroku. I was on the fence already. If anyone writes a real answer, I will give you the checkmark. I assume others have this same question.